# Find $m$ such that $4 \nmid \phi(m)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The above question is taken from Silvermans *A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory*, volume 3. Here's what I've got so far:
I know that  $$\phi(m) = \prod_{p|m} (p^{k-1})(p-1)$$ and I tried several approaches but couldn't find a good solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

*Hint* How many factors of $2$ are there in each of those $p-1$ factors appearing in the product you gave for $\phi(m)$? If $4\nmid\phi(m)$, then you're only allowed at most one factor of $2$.

Comment: The author himself!

Answer (score 2):

Take $m \geq 7$. Then if $m = 7$, then $\phi(m) = 6$, and $4$ does not divide $\phi(m)$.

Though it strikes me as odd- do you instead want $4$ to not divide $\phi(m)$?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it

Comment: I've tweaked my answer. $\phi(7) = 6$, which is not divisible by $4$.

Comment: Basically,take any prime of the form $4k+3$.Then the number of totatives will be $4k+2$,which is definitely not divisible by $4$.This can be used to show that there are infinitely many $m$  satisfying $4\nmid \phi(n)$ .

Comment: But how do you get all of them?

Answer (score 1):

From the formula you gave, $m$ can have at most one odd prime divisor or be a power of $2$ less than $8$. Moreover, that odd prime divisor must be of the form $4k+3$ not $4k+1$.

That leaves us with $m=p^e$ or $m=2p^e$, with $p=4k+3$ and $m=1,2,4$.